# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

trying to get a picture link of the object. These objects are in the array and the method in typescript looks like this:

```
getMealPicture(orderLineMeal: OrderLine): string {
    for (let meal of this.meals) {
      if (meal.id === orderLineMeal.mealId) {
        return meal.picture;
      }
    }
  }
```

returns string and this string is put in HTML:

```
<img src="{{getMealPicture(orderLineMeal)}}" alt="" class="cartMeal-picture">
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at CheckoutPageComponent.push../src/app/checkout-page/checkout-page.component.ts.CheckoutPageComponent.getMealPicture (checkout-page.component.ts:113)
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (CheckoutPageComponent.html:9)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:22482)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21857)
at callViewAction (core.js:22093)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:22056)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21853)
at callViewAction (core.js:22093)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:22035)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21858)
```

where the first row is pointing on row 113 where this HTML img tag is.
But images are there, they will just sometimes load second-two after the content is loaded. Do you think it is the problem?

this array of meals (this.meals) is taken from the service and backend .NET. So I initialized this array in constructor:

```
meals: Meal[];

this.mealService.getAllMeals().subscribe( listOfMeals => {
  this.meals = listOfMeals;
});
```

I tried everything but I wasn't able to solve this console error even though this error does not affect anything. I have a different amount of them each time I reload page. it is 2-4 usually.

I thought that it is because img src is not loaded immediately, it takes some time so I put an array init in constructor but still error.

Any thoughts? Tips? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe solvable by using `[src]="getMealPicture(orderLineMeal)"` binding instead of classic HTML attribute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Initialize the `meals` array

```
meals: Meal[] = [];
```

Comment: actually it was so small mistake that I was thinking about deletion. But for your effort I will check it. thanks

Comment: Also try to use @Zooly approach mentioned in the comments